# Aligning numbers from "lineno" package

Tags: numbering, alignment, lineno

So here's my problem (feel very sorry for not finding a solution on my own).

```
\documentclass[10pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


This is a text for an example. I want the numbers on the left of each line to be aligned with the text outside the environment.

\begin{linenumbers}
\blindtext[1]
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

By default, the `lineno` package aligns its numbering over the left of the page's margin. It looks like this:

[image]

However, I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

So, I want the numbered part to be aligned to the margin of the main text. Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're really asking to do is to change the left margin for the numbered paragraphs, so you'll need to do that in addition to changing the `\linenumbersep` length.  I've created a new environment `numbered` that does this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\newenvironment{numbered}{%
    \addtolength{\leftskip}{2\parindent}
    \setlength{\linenumbersep}{-.5\parindent}
    \begin{linenumbers}}
    {\end{linenumbers}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


This is a text for an example. I want the numbers on the left of each line to be aligned with the text outside the environment.


\begin{numbered}
\blindtext[1]
\end{numbered}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have some problems with these basic margins mechanics. Really helpful answer!!! Thanks again!!!